# Macbook pro 11,2 poor sound

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, macbook

Can anyone help to configure sound on my Macbook pro 11,2 with 16,04 ubuntu? After installation sound is very poor. changing setting in Alsamixer useless, still crappy sound.

> lspci | grep Audio
>   00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Crystal Well HD Audio Controller (rev 08)
>   00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)

Comment: still need help